# Add an extra column to this form

Tags: html, row, multiple-columns

How do I add an extra column to the form used [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simplest-contact-form)? I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/images/cdn.designinstruct.com/files/446-portfolio_website_design/portfolio_website_design_06contactinfo_example_chrismead.jpg), where there is info on the right with the form on the left. I tried adding another div under the div with class=row and floating the div with class=well left but it shrunk the form and I couldn't get it to return to its original size without sending the text underneath.
Listing code below anyways:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="well well-sm">
          <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
          <fieldset>
            <legend class="text-center">Contact us</legend>

            <!-- Name input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Email input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Your E-mail</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Message body -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">Your message</label>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="5"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Form actions -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try by adding two columns , and adding your current code, in the bigger scaled column

```html
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
 <div class="well well-sm">
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">Contact us</legend>

        <!-- Name input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Email input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Your E-mail</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Message body -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">Your message</label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Please enter your message here..." rows="5"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Form actions -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
 
</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding:40px;">
  <div class="row">
<h4>Contact Details</h4>

 <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> hello</p> 
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> hello</p>

<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> hello</p>
  <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> hello</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
<h4>Social</h4>
<p>Logos</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
<h4>Project Opportunities</h4>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```